# New users don't get a CW checkbox

Tags: support, community-wiki, new-users

New users can't post community wiki questions directly. The community wiki checkbox doesn't appear when asking the question. You have to *edit* the question after asking it and check the community wiki box.

I assume this is to prevent new users from posting a CW question before they know what CW is (since CW is irreversible). When does somebody cease to be "new user"?

Comment: I agree with the SO team that new users should be protected, but perhaps the box could be disabled with a little question mark next to it to explain why it is disabled.

Although honestly, I doubt a beginner would have a need for a CW question.

Comment: @HalfBrian: since it can be done with a workaround, that is simply putting sharp objects out of the reach of children, isn't it?  Maybe the benefits of a change are outweighed by the "How do I turn back my CW to being a CW question" questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<add key="Reputation.NeededForAbility.Newbie" value="10" />
```

Comment: Is it just me or have your answers been getting more and more cryptic lately?

Comment: The cross is Mexico. Mexico is the walnut. The hazelnut. The acorn. Mexico is the rainbow. The rainbow is wooden. Mexico is wooden.

Comment: Wow man... is that the swine flu hitting in?

Comment: Pro-tip: Trilogy use while under the influence of mescaline is not generally recommended. :)