# new user made answer community wiki?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are “Community Wiki” posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

From my understanding is that new users cannot create posts as community wiki - based on:

[New users don't get a CW checkbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32657/new-users-dont-get-a-cw-checkbox)

> New users can't post community wiki questions directly

[What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)

> The answer's author checks the community wiki checkbox when composing the answer. Note that this checkbox isn't available to new users.

However, during a review, I noticed that [this new user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1947618/hulala666) somehow made their [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213100/jscrollpane-words-wrap/14151971#14151971) CW right away.

Is this a bug? How should this type of thing be communicated to new users?

**Edit** apparently I missed the part of the same FAQ question linked above that answers my question:

> An answer posted to a Community Wiki question will also be Community Wiki

Comment: I think any new answers to CW questions are automatically CW as well.

Comment: Ah, yes - it's in the FAQ you linked to.  "*An answer posted to a Community Wiki question will also be Community Wiki. Note that when a question is made CW after answers have already been posted, the existing answers are not normally converted to CW automatically.*"

Comment: duh-oi - I wonder how I missed that almost right under where I was reading. First time reviewing a CW answer had me a bit confused I guess.

Comment: Heh, it happens =)

Comment: So not being as up on meta etiquette - do I delete/close/edit this question?

Comment: @Chris: Ignore that first question you linked. That's from 2009, over 3 years old. The community wiki rules have changed drastically since then. **Any user** can mark their own *answer* as community wiki, any time, whether the question is CW or not. Just read the "How does a post become a Community Wiki post?" section of the FAQ you linked. It lists all the possible ways a post can become community wiki. FAQs are consistently updated to reflect the most current standards for how the site works, so if there's a red FAQ tag, you should trust that over anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a question is community wiki, any following posts to that question will be community wiki. Note that the user's post was subject to the First Post review queue, and was deemed No Action Needed.

If it were not in the First Post queue (being, if it were not the user's first post), it would  (if I'm correct here) be added to the Late Answers queue for users under a certain amount of reputation. Thus, even though it's community wiki, the answer is still moderated.